JSF: selectItem noSelectOptions not setting null to value due to validator attribute
I have following code:
                <h:selectOneMenu id="selectDocumentType"
                                 required="true"
                                 requiredMessage="#{of:format1(msg['validation.field.required'], msg['configuration.doc.new.type.document'])}"
                                 value="#{dcNewEditBean.documentConfiguration.type}"
                                 styleClass="-width-100 -form-select">
                    <p:ajax event="change" process="@this" listener="#{dcNewEditBean.isSelectedType()}"
                            update="#{p:component('panel_max_docs')} #{p:component('roles_for_view')}"/>
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{msg['menu.export.tab.checkbox.choose']}" itemValue="#{null}"
                                  noSelectionOption="true"/>
                    <f:selectItems value="#{dcNewEditBean.availableDocumentTypes}" var="documentType"
                                   itemLabel="#{msg[documentType.key]}"/>
                </h:selectOneMenu>

After selection label menu.export.tab.checkbox.choose it changes on the front to my specified message, but in backend on dcNewEditBean.documentConfiguration.type variable there's previously choosen value, not null.
That's intresting that if I remove required and requiredMessage attributtes, value null is passed to the backend and debugger stops on my isSelectedType() function, with required/requiredMessage debugger doesn't stop and on isSelectedType() and value of dcNewEditBean.documentConfiguration.type is not null, but the value previously set before null.
Do You know why is this happening?
